# How to preserve HTTP Status for response when using SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring Boot application with Spring Security 6 I wanna use a `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and set the HTTP Staus Code to `401`:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /* Should make it easier for XHR requests to distinguish between success and failure. */
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        super.setDefaultFailureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the status code set in the `onAuthenticationFailure` method doesn't make it to the LOGIN_FAILURE_URL endpoint. Instead, the status code gets being set to `200`.

Is there a way to preserve the HTTP Status Code during the whole cycle, once being set?

**Many thanks for any help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because by default `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` sends a HTTP redirect request to the failure URL . It is a new HTTP request and hence the HTTP status code you configured in the previous request 's response will not be preserved.

So try to configure `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` to forward the request to the failure URL rather than a HTTP redirect by :

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /* Should make it easier for XHR requests to distinguish between success and failure. */
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        super.setUseForward(true);
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately `setUseForward` breaks it completely and all I get is a `405` response. Also fyi, the `HttpServletRequest` isn't get altered or newly created, the information inside the request seems to be preserved. It's only the response, but you may be right, that the response get's cleared. Do you have any other ideas handy? My current workaround is to use a FlashMap to get the information to the controller, but this seems more like an ugly hack than a decent coding style.

Comment: guess that you are POSTing the request to do authentication. 405 means the endpoint `LOGIN_FAILURE_URL` does not support POST. So can you try to configure this endpoint to support POST too ? In case it is a `@Controller` method, you can do it by `@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})`

Comment: Just because I'm curious: I've used a FlashMap bevore your solution, and I've recognized, that this FlashMap isn't available anymore when using forward and setting the `outputFlashMap.setTargetRequestPath(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)`. Without `setTargetRequestPath` the map is accessible. Do you know why this is?